# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" while Dropdown removing item

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a dropdown binding with resx file. When i am going to remove some value, after first loop of foreach I am getting error:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Code

```
foreach (ListItem item in VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items)
{
    if (!availableVoucherTypesArray.Contains(int.Parse(item.Value)))
    {                
        VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.Remove(
            VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(item.Value.ToString()));
    }
}
```

how to fix this one please ?

==>**I have solved this way**

```
 for (Int32 i = VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
        ListItem item = VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items[i];

        if (!availableVoucherTypesArray.Contains(int.Parse(item.Value)))
        {
            VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.Remove(VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(item.Value.ToString()));            
        }
        }
```

Now its working fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify an enumeration while iterating through it. You will have to remember the item you want to remove and remove it after the foreach loop.

```
List<object> items = new List<object> { 1, 2 };
object objectToRemove = null;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    // insert your condition
    if (false)
    {
        objectToRemove = item;
        break;
    }
}

if (objectToRemove != null)
    items.Remove(objectToRemove);
```

Comment: I solved this way : 
 for (Int32 i = VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
        ListItem item = VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items[i];

        if (!availableVoucherTypesArray.Contains(int.Parse(item.Value)))
        {
         
            VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.Remove(VoucherTypeDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(item.Value.ToString()));            
        }
        }